# Spring MVC - How to support both http and https at the same time in Spring MVC web project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ssl

How can I support both HTTP and https at the same time in Spring MVC web project deployed on tomcat7 (and 8). I have configured every thing at Tomcat level.

HTTPS work if I use the following code by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
.and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
```

but then it does not allow HTTP, I need to support **both** HTTP AND HTTPS at the **same time** for **same endpoint**
example:

```
http://example.com/hello-world
https://example.com/hello-world
```

Comment: Look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/732757/configure-ssl-in-apache-with-tomcat-7-and-spring-mvc-webapp)

Comment: I agree with @Zico: the correct way it to have HTTPS processing done at a reverse proxy level. That way everything is by default accepted with both HTTP and HTTPS. And if you want to require HTTPS for only some more sensitive URL, you could have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129124/3545273) from mine.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your `https` configuration from `.anyRequest()` to a specific secure url eg. `http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/secure*").requiresSecure();` and making the rest Insecure as follows  `http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresInsecure();` will solve the issue.

This instructs Spring to use HTTP for all requests that are not explicitly configured to use HTTPS.

Comment: Actually, I want to support the same endpoint from both http and https

Comment: I don't think that is logically possible, If you make an endpoint `requireSecure()` it can not be accessed insecurely (ie. via http).